# I'm trying to make a searcher but when i send a request from my frontend in react Django doesn't get the data sent

Tags: python, reactjs, django, api

Sorry for my English.
When I'm trying to get the data sent in the frontend (it seems its working well because is generating a JSON with the search value) the function in Django is not getting the data that I sent, the print(search) returns None
This is my code in Django:
views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def search_locations(request):
    search = request.POST.get('search')
    print(search)
    results = []
    if search:
        locations = Location.objects.filter(name=search)
        print(locations)
        for location in locations:
            results.append({
                'id': location.id,
                'name': location.name,
                'latitude': location.latitude,
                'longitude': location.longitude
            })
    return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('locations/', LocationsView.as_view(), name='locations'),
    path('locations/search/', search_locations, name='search_locations'),
    path('locations/<int:pk>/', location_detail, name='location_detail'),
]
```

React code:

```
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

 const handleSearch = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  await axios
    .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/apilocations/locations/search/", {
      search: searchValue,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      setPlaces(response.data);
      console.log(searchValue)
      console.log(response)
      console.log(places)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

When I use the searcher search return None

Comment: `search = request.POST.get` vs `await axios.post`. Is that correct?